# Communication between Ubuntu on WSL2 and Windows is spotty after startup

Tags: windows-10, wsl2

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL 2 on my Windows 10 computer. On most, if not all days, I find that when I start Ubuntu, communication between Ubuntu and Windows is spotty, with symptoms like:

- The C drive is not mounted as `/mnt/c`
- Apache running on the Ubuntu system is not exposed to Windows, meaning I can't access it from a Chrome browser window on Windows.

I have found that running `wsl --shutdown` in PowerShell and starting Ubuntu afterwards normally fixes the problem, but it is somewhat annoying having to do that every single time I start up my computer.

Why does this happen, and how can I automatically make Ubuntu start up without having the problems above, and without having to manually shut down wsl first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

Do you hibernate?  Any form of hibernation tends to cause connectivity issues between WSL and the host.  The inability to access services like Apache from your Windows host is definitely something I've seen (through various [Stack posts and votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455770/11810933)) often.

Or, if you shut down your computer entirely, do you have Windows "Fast Startup" enabled (it's the default, so unless you have disabled it, it's there).  Fast Startup is a form of hibernation as well and is known to cause WSL issues.

It's fairly likely that this is the cause of the Apache issue, at least.  Not quite as sure about the intermittent failure to mount the Windows drives, though.

Comment: I don't hibernate explicitly, but fast startup was enabled, so I will be trying that. My best guess is that the mounted c-drive is due to the same problem, as it is basically somewhat of a network drive at that point and the connection is failing to re-establish. Most people wont use the mount under wsl2 anyway, because the performance is bad (at least compared to wsl1 or regular drive actions). I'll be back once I have verified this works for me.

Comment: Right - I'm *hopeful* that the mount issue will be related for that same reason.  And yeah, I keep a WSL1 instance around for any time I need to handle files on my NTFS drives (e.g. backups using `rsync` or `s3cmd`).